# display error message if ID not found

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have one simple html form where the fields can be auto populated by entering ID. its working fine. but, if ID not found in database, it can only return null to the form fields. i was trying to display an error message (can be a pop-up window) saying **ID not found!** but i failed to do it. here is my code to echo info into the form field:

```
if (strlen($param) > 0) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact 
     WHERE contactid LIKE '$param%'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $agentname = $myrow["contactfullname"];
            $agenttel = $myrow["contacttel"];
            $agentsal = $myrow["contactsalutation"];
            $agentid = $myrow["contactid"];
            $textout .= $agentid . ", " . $agentname . ", " . $agenttel . ", " . $agentsal;
        }
    } else {
        $textout = " , , ," . $param;
    }
}
echo $textout;
```

here is my ajaxFunction:

```
function ajaxFunction(e){
    var e=e || window.event;
    var keycode=e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(keycode==13 || (e.target||e.srcElement).value==''){ 
    var http;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible! 

    try{ 
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari 
        http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } catch (e){ 
        // Internet Explorer Browsers 
        try{ 
            http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
        } catch (e) { 
            try{ 
                http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
            } catch (e){ 
                // Something went wrong 
                alert("Your browser broke!"); 
                return false; 
            } 
        }
    }
 var url = "getagentids.php?param=";
                var idValue = document.getElementById("agid").value;
                var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random()*99999999);  // cache buster
                http.open("GET", "getagentids.php?param=" + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true);
                http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
                http.send(null);

                function handleHttpResponse() {
                    if (http.readyState == 4) {
                        results = http.responseText.split(",");
                        document.getElementById('agfn').value = results[0];
                        document.getElementById('agsal').value = results[1];
                        document.getElementById('agtel').value = results[2];
                        document.getElementById('agid').value = results[3];
                    }
           } 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Could you also add your ajax code, it may turn out you could `echo '<script>alert("ID not found");</script>';` in the else portion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Dont use mysql_* functions, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.
2. [take care](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) about $param value
3. If your query should return 1 result, you can use [LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) 1 , and also there is no need to use while.

change this :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact 
     WHERE contactid LIKE '$param%'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact 
     WHERE contactid LIKE '$escaped_param%' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
     $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

4.  if you want to show a message on your ajax response, you can use json or .... as an simple example, return this string on error :

```
error|" , , ," . $param;
```

and to check if an error occured on your client :

```
var result = "error|anything";
if(result.substr(0,6) == 'error|')
{
    alert('An error occured.');
}
else
{
    //do what you need!
}
```

**Edit :**

```
function handleHttpResponse() 
{
    if (http.readyState == 4) 
    {
        results = http.responseText;
        if(results.substr(0,6) == 'error|')
        {
            alert('An error occured.');
        }
        else
        {
            results = results.split(",");
            document.getElementById('agfn').value = results[0];
            document.getElementById('agsal').value = results[1];
            document.getElementById('agtel').value = results[2];
            document.getElementById('agid').value = results[3];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i can't understand where to add `var result = "error|anything";
if(result.substr(0,6) == 'error|')
{
    alert('An error occured.');
}
else
{
    //do what you need!
}`. i've tried but if the **ID** exists, still the pop-up coming out and after that populating the form.. I've added my ajaxFunction here, may be you can help me how to solve it out..

Comment: your welcome, in you javascript ajax function, var result was an example, result is the return answer of your php code. please show us your ajax code.

Answer (score 1):

try do this in your sql

```
 LIKE '%" . $param . "%'
```